# Apache2. Custom same error page for all virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to set the same custom error pages 'globally' once for all for every virtual host.

I tried placing

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
```

inside

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages
```

or

```
/etcf/apache2/apache2.conf
```

but these settings work only if I type a non-existent page using the IP of my VPS as for example 32.56.210.12/blahblah and not if I try with a non-existent page on a virtual host. In this case the canonical error is displayed "The requested URL /blahblah was not found on this server."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html), `ErrorDocument` directive can have actions that can be either text, external url or local url, examples:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/crash-recover 
ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear" 
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /Lame_excuses/not_found.html
```

This means it has to be a redirect or an url within the `VirtualHost`'s own `DocumentRoot`. You could achieve this by making it a global alias, e.g.:

```
Alias /error/404.html /var/www/error/404.html
```